# http 400 error Elasticsearch --query to retrieve documents containing any of the keywords in an array

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a huge number of keywords written in a file. I put them in an array and tried to run a query for each of the item in the array and retrieve the documents that have any of the keywords. It shows me the number of returned documents only for 50 of them and at the end I get a couple of errors. 
**Here is  my code:**

**A subset of keywords:**

```
C0001396    SYNDROME STOKES-ADAMS
C0001396    Syndrome, Adams-Stokes
C0001396    Syndrome, Stokes-Adams
C0002962    3-12 ANGINAL SYNDROMES
C0002962    ANGINA
```

**The CODE:**

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import json
count=0
keyword_array = []
es = Elasticsearch(['http://IP:9200/'])
with open('localDrive\\C0577785C.txt') as my_keywordfile:
    for keyword in my_keywordfile.readlines():
        keyword_ex=keyword[9:]
        print(keyword_ex)
        keyword_array.append(keyword_ex.strip().strip("'"))

with open('localDrive\\out.txt', 'wb') as f:
    for x in keyword_array:
        doc = {

                "from" : 0, "size" : 1000000,
                "query":{
                    "query_string":{
                        "fields" : ["description", "title"],
                         "query" : x
                                   }
                 }

              }
        res = es.search(index='INDEXED_REPO', body=doc)
        print("Got %d Hits:" % res['hits']['total'])
        count += 1
        print(count)
        f.write(json.dumps(res).encode("utf-8"))
        f.flush()
    f.close()
```

**Errors:**

```
GET http://INDEX_REPO/indexed/_search [status:400 request:0.012s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
"localDrive/PycharmProjects/extract_keywords/elastic_serach5.py", line 
32, in <module>
    res = es.search(index='INDEXED_REPO', body=doc)
  File "......\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\elasticsearch\client\utils.py", line 73, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "....\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\elasticsearch\client\__init__.py", line 623, in search
    doc_type, '_search'), params=params, body=body)
  File "......\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\elasticsearch\transport.py", line 312, in perform_request
    status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, 
 body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "......\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
 packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py", line 128, in 
 perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "......\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\elasticsearch\connection\base.py", line 125, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, 
error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: <exception str() failed>
```

Any idea why it is happening?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The elasticsearch query was not in the right format. I changed it to the following and it worked!:

```
  doc = {
    "query": { 
        "multi_match": {
                "query": x,
                "type": "phrase",
                "fields": ["title", "description"],   
                "operator": "and"
               }
             }
          }
```